# Resolving Controller Services in Sylius/Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

Hoes does Symfony resolve the [Sylius](https://github.com/sylius/sylius) service `sylius.controller.shop_user` service to the controller class file `Sylius\Bundle\UserBundle\Controller\UserController`.

My understanding is that `sylius.controller.shop_user` is a service, and that in Symfony there will be a corresponding service configuration.  This service configuration will tell Symfony which class to use when it needs to instantiate the service.

However, I can't seem to find a `sylius.controller.shop_user` configuration in the Sylius source configuration anywhere.  There's just references to this service in routing files

```
#File: src/Sylius/Bundle/ShopBundle/Resources/config/routing/ajax/user.yml
sylius_shop_ajax_user_check_action:
    path: /check
    methods: [GET]
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.controller.shop_user:showAction
        _format: json
        _sylius:
            repository:
                method: findOneByEmail
                arguments:
                    email: $email
            serialization_groups: [Secured]
```

or in on-disk container cache files.

```
var/cache/dev/srcKernelDevDebugContainer.xml
1798:    <parameter key="sylius.controller.shop_user.class">Sylius\Bundle\UserBundle\Controller\UserController</parameter>
15230:    <service id="sylius.controller.shop_user" class="Sylius\Bundle\UserBundle\Controller\UserController" public="true">
```

So how does Symfony know to instantiate the right class for this service?

Is there configuration I'm not seeing?  Some Symfony magic that auto-generates the class?  Some other mysterious third thing where I don't know what I don't know?

I don't have any specific task in mind, I'm just trying to get a feel for how Sylius and Symfony work under the hood.

Comment: It is probably configured dynamically in the SyliusBundle dependency injection Extension class.  Just a guess but the Extension class is where most of the di magic tends to occur.

Comment: @Cerad as part of Symfony's normal dynamic controller handler? Or something special Sylius is doing? Or something else?

Comment: I have not peeked under the hood for Sylius but the extension is where services are usually defined.  If it is not defined in the extension itself the almost certainly in a compiler pass.  A controller is nothing special.  Symfony routing will pull any service you specify for _controller and call the action on it.  Try a search through the entire code base for shop_user.  That should take you right to the definition.

Comment: So out of curiosity I loaded Sylius and poked around a bit.  It is indeed a huge project.  Many many many levels of abstraction.  @pamil's answer below is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services with the name `sylius.controller.[entity-name]` are part of the
Sylius 
[entity resource system](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.3/cookbook/entities/custom-model.html).  As best I can tell, when you define your new doctrine entities
in a specific way and 
[register them as a Sylius resource](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.3/cookbook/entities/custom-model.html#register-your-entity-as-a-sylius-resource), Sylius will
automatically generate these controller services based on your
configuration.

The actual line of code that defines these services 
[is here](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/977081be9d528563fa35ad669d054dcb9f03d914/src/Sylius/Bundle/ResourceBundle/DependencyInjection/Driver/AbstractDriver.php#L89).

```
#File: src/Sylius/Bundle/ResourceBundle/DependencyInjection/Driver/AbstractDriver.php
/* ... */
$container->setDefinition($metadata->getServiceId('controller'), $definition);
/* ... */
```

The
`Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\DependencyInjection\Driver\AbstractDriver`
class is a (as of 1.3) a base class for the
`Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\DependencyInjection\Driver\Doctrine\DoctrineORMDriver` 
class. How this class ends up being used is by Symfony is unclear, but is 
fortunately beyond the scope of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The controller service is defined based on ResourceBundle's configuration in `Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\DependencyInjection\Driver\AbstractDriver::addController`. This driver is called when loading a bundle.